# How to set dependency of android gradle project to different versions of library?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have small log library and it is published to jcenter. I need to have two versions of the library - debug and release. To do this I found flag `publishNonDefault true` and pushed new version of library.

Structure of files in repository before flag was set:
[image: 1.2.4]
Structure of files in repository after flag was set:
[image: 1.3.1]

And now
`dependencies { 
        compile 'me.shikhov:wlog:1.3.1'
    }`

gives me error

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':Project'.
 Could not find wlog.jar (me.shikhov:wlog:1.3.1).
   Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/me/shikhov/wlog/1.3.1/wlog-1.3.1.jar
```

I have found syntax for local dependency, for example:

`debugCompile project(path: ':myLocalLibrary', configuration: 'debug')`

`releaseCompile project(path: ':myLocalLibrary', configuration: 'debug')`

How to set remote library dependency?

Comment: As you can see it is renamed to `me.shikhov:wlog:1.3.1-release` now, so all you have to do is use `compile 'me.shikhov:wlog:1.3.1-release'`

Comment: @DanielZolnai I already tried all possible variants, even with "@aar" notation - failed to resolve: me.shikhov:wlog:1.3.1-release

Comment: Check inside the pom file which is the artifact id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra string after the version in the artifact name is the classifier.

> The classifier allows to distinguish artifacts that were built from
>   the same POM but differ in their content. It is some optional and
>   arbitrary string that - if present - is appended to the artifact name
>   just after the version number. As a motivation for this element,
>   consider for example a project that offers an artifact targeting JRE
>   1.5 but at the same time also an artifact that still supports JRE 1.4. The first artifact could be equipped with the classifier jdk15 and the
>   second one with jdk14 such that clients can choose which one to use.
>
> Another common use case for classifiers is the need to attach
>   secondary artifacts to the project's main artifact. If you browse the
>   Maven central repository, you will notice that the classifiers sources
>   and javadoc are used to deploy the project source code and API docs
>   along with the packaged class files.

From [here](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html).

Gradle dependency declaration takes the form:

```
[organisation]:[module]:[revision]:[classifier]@[ext]
```

so you should be consuming the dependency as:

```
compile 'me.shikhov:wlog:1.3.1:release@aar'
```